# Keyboard Shift+2 showing @ not double marks

Tags: keyboard-layout, input-language

My keyboard suddenly starting acting like a Mac, so get `@` when I want a double quote marks `"`.

May be obvious, but how do I revert it back. It has just suddenly happened, I don't even know why? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your keyboard layout.

To do this just go on *System Settings* > *Text Entry* and then put your keyboard layout at the top like in this picture:

[image]

You can also quick switch from this icon on the top bar:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! the 2nd option worked for me, must of accidently changed it without realising.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Please read this if the answer was helpful http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers